# Ipad / IOS hover issues

Tags: ios, css

In my site there are a few thumbnail when u hover, there will be text coming out.

In android it is perfect, when u touch the thumbnail, the text will appear before the thumbnail go into the slideshow.

But in IOS, the text will not appear and straight away go to the slideshow.

[The thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VGF4.jpg)

This is my css

```
.text {
background-color: rgba(183, 191, 183, 0.65);
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding-top:40%;
padding-left:2%;
cursor: pointer;

.middle {
transition: .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: .5s ease ;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How about linking it to my site, is that ok ?

Comment: No, the code should be _within_ the question, and the reason is; when a linked resource dies, so does the value of this question and its answers.

Comment: I think i already described the question as best as possible. See the attached image. the thumbnails, when hovered will have the text effect coming out. It works fine in comp. In android it works correctly when touched, the text will come out first before proceeding to the slideshow. But in IOS, it will proceed to the slideshow straight away without the hover effects

Comment: If you don't follow the rules and recommendations [_how to ask a question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), don't expect any proper answers